# Stability of clusters/mixtures from GMMs

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, model-based-clustering

## Some background

I have a data set with around 2000 samples and 16 features. Me and my colleague are trying out different methods for clustering and currently we are converging to the usage of a Gaussian Mixture Model.

We established that according to an information criterion, the best number of mixtures is 6.

Then we received 200 more samples and ran the clustering again. In this case the number of clusters remains the same, but one of the old clusters got severely split up among the other ones.

My colleague is a psychologist, so he had invested some time in interpreting the old clusters and was rather unsatisfied with the change when the new data arrived. I am trying to convince him that we need to investigate the stability of the clusters in order to understand if there are any particular groups in the data that stand out, i.e. is there any true stable underlying structure.

So I came across [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0005046.pdf), which has been cited around 260 times, so I went to try it out. I can calculate the figure of merit mentioned in the article and this looks like a reasonable way to go forward, but for 5 samples of half the data, it is rather small.

I have also reordered the data according to the clustering of the whole data set. This gives me a connectivity matrix like the one below, you can see that some of the groups are rather small.

[image: Original Connectivity]

Now for the 5 resamples I get the following connectivity, where connectivity is the average number of times there was a connection in the 5 resamples. The original structure remains, but some of the clusters split/mix up more than others. I intend to run this 1000 times to get a better feel for what is going on.

[image: Imgur]

## My questions

So I have a few questions regarding estimating the stability of clusters in general, and what to do about it.

- I resample only half of the data, should I be resampling more? Or maybe just create bootstrap samples and remove duplicates?
- If some of the clusters are splitting up a lot, is the right way to go forward to merge those clusters or just use the most stable ones? I guess this is a subjective question, depending on the end goal, but I would like to here a generic answer if someone has some input in that regard.
- Can you point me to any case studies or more reliable sources on this matter?